# Vigenere Cipher Issues

Tags: java, encryption

I am relatively new to programming and trying to get a Vigenere cipher to work properly. I took some recommendations from a few different ciphers, but I am playing with one now that does not work if I modify it. If I change the password to its original "VigenereCipher" instead of "apple" it works perfectly. What is it about my code that is creating this problem?  I apologize for the code being messy, but I have been copying and pasting to test various edits to the code.

> Output :

```
sealseals ealse
FCJJMUMPJB
.+225=582*
```

> Expected Output:

```
sealsealse
encryptedcode (not sure if this is correct above)
HELLOWORLD
```

The code:

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String key = "apple";
            String ori = "hello world"; 
            String resizedKey = key;
            if (key.length() < ori.length()) {
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < ori.length(); i ++) {
                if (ori.charAt(i) == (char)32) {
                    resizedKey += (char)32;
                }
                else {
                    if (j < key.length()) {
                        resizedKey += key.charAt(j);
                        j++;
                    }
                    else {
                        j = 0;
                        resizedKey += key.charAt(j);
                        j++;
                        }                           
                }
            }
        }
                System.out.println (resizedKey);
                String enc = encrypt(ori, resizedKey);
                System.out.println(enc);
                System.out.println(decrypt(enc, resizedKey));

        }                       
        static String encrypt(String text, final String key) {
            String res = "";
            text = text.toUpperCase();
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                char c = text.charAt(i);
                if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') continue;
                res += (char)((c + key.charAt(j) - 2 * 'A') % 26 + 'A');
            }
            return res;
        }
         static String decrypt(String text, final String key) {
            String res = "";
            text = text.toUpperCase();
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                char c = text.charAt(i);
                if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') continue;
                res += (char)((c - key.charAt(j) + 26) % 26 + 'A');
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In `decrypt` i see that you never increment `j` so you always decrypt with the first letter of your `key`. Maybe that's part of your problem?

Comment: Also, `"apple"` starts with a lower case letter, which seems you neglect in your calculations when appending to the result `res`.

Comment: I stuck that in as a test example and forgot to capitalize it. I fixed the oddity by just making the who key uppercase. It solved the problem. Thanks for the advice. Fixed, so I appreciate it.

Comment: Great, although you only use the first character of the key, so technically It's a Cesar's cipher, not Vigenere's.